# How to change pgsql now() time?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm having an error on my system with some timescale matherialized views, but this only happens after 22 hrs.

I can´t access the office's computer at that hour and I should not be working at that time, so for me to debug the problem I would like to change the computer's time to pretend it's 22 at 9 am.

I changed the computer's time and restarted the psql docker image, but it still marks the current time when `select now()`.

I can find many posts and documentation about changing the timezone, but I just want the server to belive that current time is today's late night.

Is there any way for doing this?

thanks

ps: I'm working on windows 10, and pg12.

Comment: Make sure your Docker doesn't have an NTP configured; it will automatically reset time from Internet.

Comment: You are right that it seems to be related to the docker container.
How can I check NTP on windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the time of your session, so that you can perform your tests, e.g. current time - 5 hours

```
SELECT now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2022-02-03 13:01:35.580786+00
(1 row)

SET timezone = -5;

SELECT now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2022-02-03 08:01:47.569613-05
(1 row)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7bced4911d4139d4727f1227d27c7813)